# Should old acquaintance be forgot,

Tags: meaning-in-context, lyrics

1. Should old acquaintance be forgot, 
   and old lang syne?
2. Should old acquaintance be forgot, 
   and should old lang syne be forgot?

---

Does #1 mean #2?

auld lang sine or old lang sine means "the old days" according to Cambridge dictionary. [ Auld lang syne means "the old days" in Scots.]

[Auld Lang Syne means ‘for old time’s sake’. - Macmillan Dictionary]

Are 'the old days' the same as ‘for old time’s sake’?

---

And we'll take a cup o' kindness yet, 
 for auld lang syne.

---

Q1: What is the meaning of 'yet' here?
 Q2: for aud lang syne is ________________ in plain English.
 What is similar to 'for auld lang syne' in easy English?

If 'for auld lang syne' is 'for days gone by,' to celebrate days gone buy, lets meet and drink kindly.  Is this the meaning of the words in the song?

Answer (score 2):

These are lyrics, and lyrics that mix English with Scots, two different languages. We don't expect the "rules" of English (or of Scots) to be obeyed!

The setting of the poem is the meeting of two old friends who haven't seen each other since childhood.

The first verse asks a rhetorical question: Should we forget our old friends and the "good old days"?  Burns phrases it as a question but means "We shouldn't forget old friends and the good old days".

In the next verse, "yet" means "still" (a meaning it yet has in modern English): You'll have your cup; I'll have mine. We'll meet and drink together and remember the "good old days".

Comment: Wouldn't that be Scottish English and Scots?